# Get count of "loglevel" for each "name"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example I have following collection:

> db.names.find({})

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9b4bc6f464899594570"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9d5bc6f464899594571"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9dcbc6f464899594572"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "WARNING" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9dfbc6f464899594573"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "WARNING" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9e0bc6f464899594574"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "WARNING" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9e7bc6f464899594575"), "name" : "t1", "loglevel" : "INFO" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9f3bc6f464899594576"), "name" : "t2", "loglevel" : "INFO" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768d9f9bc6f464899594577"), "name" : "t2", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768da19bc6f464899594578"), "name" : "t2", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768da1abc6f464899594579"), "name" : "t2", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768da1bbc6f46489959457a"), "name" : "t2", "loglevel" : "ERROR" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5768e247bc6f46489959457b"), "name" : "t3", "loglevel" : "INFO" }
```

I have tried but I think it should be better solution (also `else` can be omitted)

```
db.names.aggregate(
    {$group: {
        _id: "$name",
        error: {$sum: {$cond: {if: {$eq: ['$loglevel', 'ERROR']}, then: {$sum: 1}, else: {$sum: 0}}}},
        warning: {$sum: {$cond: {if: {$eq: ['$loglevel', 'WARNING']}, then: {$sum: 1}, else: {$sum: 0}}}},
        info: {$sum: {$cond: {if: {$eq: ['$loglevel', 'INFO']}, then: {$sum: 1}, else: {$sum: 0}}}}
    }}
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `{ "$sum": 1 }` and `{ "$sum": 0 }` expressions in your `if/else` conditional blocks, substitute them with the values 1 and 0 (respectively for each conditional block).

The final pipeline should look like this, using the other **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** syntax which omits the `if/else` blocks:

```
db.names.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$name",
            "error": { 
               "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$loglevel",  "ERROR" ] }, 1, 0] 
               }
           },
           "warning":{
               "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$loglevel", "WARNING" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
           },
           "info": { 
               "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$loglevel",  "INFO" ] }, 1, 0 ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
])
```

---

Or dynamically create the pipeline, given an array of possible statuses:

```
var statuses = ["ERROR", "WARNING", "INFO"],
    groupOperator = { "$group": { "_id": "$name" } };

statuses.forEach(function (status){ 
    groupOperator["$group"][status.toLowerCase()] = { 
       "$sum": { 
           "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$loglevel",  status ] }, 1, 0] 
       }
   }
});

db.names.aggregate([groupOperator]);
```

**Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "t1",
    "error" : 2,
    "warning" : 3,
    "info" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "t2",
    "error" : 4,
    "warning" : 0,
    "info" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "t3",
    "error" : 0,
    "warning" : 0,
    "info" : 1
}
```

Comment: good point about if/else blocks, but still I'm looking for DRY solution (don't duplicate loglevel's block)

Comment: @madzohan Updated my answer to include the DRY approach.

Comment: nice! also could you tell me which way would be better (performance, etc) - keep logic like grouping in mongodb or move it to programming language such as python?

Comment: I wouldn't know as I haven't done any benchmark tests on the performance but would like to think the differences in performance (if any) would be negligible since you you will just be essentially running the same pipeline whether dynamically created or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the sum of loglevels against each name.
shouldn't this help?

```
   db.names.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{name:"$name",loglevel:"$loglevel"},sum:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Comment: yep I've tried this earlier, but I need it in grouped way by `$name` with all loglevels annotated

Comment: right. just saw @Chridam's answer. guess that's what you looking for.