# MapReduce in mongo db is taking 0 input for large data

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo db and map reduce and am stuck with this problem.
below is my collections document format:-

```
`{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("57c9b650d803090f7e43864c"), 
   "imei" : "2670988969039437", 
   "model" : "XYX", 
   "cId" : "168", 
   "src" : "XYZZZ", 
   "feedback" : "downloaded_gcm", 
   "ts" : "2016-08-04 09:51:18" 
 }`
```

My queries work when i tested it on a collections with 50000 documents  but its returning wrong result on a collections with 50,00,000 documents.

below is my map reduce query:

```
`
db.colectionNAme.mapReduce(
function() {
    var key = this.model;
    var val = {
        installed : 0,
        received : 0,
        gcm_cancel : 0,
        downloaded_gcm : 0,
        gcm_acticated : 0,
        gcm_ok : 0
    };

     if(this.feedback == "installed") {
        val.installed++;
    } else if(this.feedback == "received") {
        val.received++;
    } else if(this.feedback == "gcm_cancel") {
        val.gcm_cancel++;
    } else if(this.feedback == "downloaded_gcm") {
        val.downloaded_gcm++;
    } else if(this.feedback == "gcm_acticated") {
        val.gcm_acticated++;
    } else if(this.feedback == "gcm_ok") {
        val.gcm_ok++;
    }
    emit(key, val);
},

function(key,values) {
    var val = {
        installed : 0,
        received : 0,
        gcm_cancel : 0,
        downloaded_gcm : 0,
        gcm_acticated : 0,
        gcm_ok : 0
    };

    values.forEach(function( value ) {
        val.installed += value.installed;
        val.received += value.received;
        val.gcm_cancel += value.gcm_cancel;
        val.downloaded_gcm += value.downloaded_gcm;
        val.gcm_acticated += value.gcm_acticated;
        val.gcm_ok += value.gcm_ok;
    });

    return val;
},
{   
    query:{cId : "166"},
    out:"mapRedResults",
    sort:{model:1},
    jsMode: true,
    usev8 :true
}
);`
```

and this is the output it gives:-

```
{
  "result" : "mapRedResults",
  "timeMillis" : 2221,
  "counts" : {
    "input" : 0,
    "emit" : 0,
    "reduce" : 0,
    "output" : 0
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

As its is evident from the result ..it takes 0 inputs....
Please note I am doing it on a amazon t2.micro ec2 instance

Comment: Have you considered creating an aggregation pipeline for the same task yet more efficient? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938257/get-count-of-loglevel-for-each-name/

Comment: @chridam ... Yes....I have already done this using aggregation ...but I wanted to do it using mapreduce.....

Comment: @chridam : thanks for your suggestion..but could you please explain if theres any thing wrong with what i am doin....because i am really not able to figure out the defect there..... I want to go with map reduce because i am getting loads of data every day and want to use incremental map reduce on that....

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pinpoint exactly where the issue is but would cheat more towards a solution that uses the aggregation framework to do the exact same thing but with greater performance than MapReduce because AF pipelines are optimized as it runs "within" MongoDB in its C++ code as the aggregation framework while MapReduce on the other hand runs within a V8/spidermonkey (depending on your version) environment within the bundled JS console in a separate thread and use the code you provide to emit and reduce parts of your document to aggregate on certain fields.

Comment: @chridam  thanks for explaining that....but any idea why this is working when i have a smaller collection... i mean it works perfect in a collection with 50k docs but ceases to work on a collection with 5000k documents...PS: i have also tried it on EC2 medium instance now

Comment: @chridam db.mapRedResults.find() doesn't return anything as that collection is blank.

Comment: @chridam : thanks a ton man... u rock..... it worked for me :) :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't pinpoint exactly where the issue is but would cheat more towards a solution that uses the aggregation framework to do the exact same thing but with greater performance than MapReduce because AF pipelines are optimized as it runs "within" MongoDB in its C++ code as the aggregation framework while MapReduce on the other hand runs within a V8/spidermonkey (depending on your version) environment within the bundled JS console in a separate thread and use the code you provide to emit and reduce parts of your document to aggregate on certain fields.

For a solution that uses the aggregation framework, you could look at [Get count of “loglevel” for each “name”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938257/get-count-of-loglevel-for-each-name/) for pointers.

---

If you're stuck with mapReduce for some reason or another, I would suggest you refactor the code to avoid unnecessary variable checks and assignments by creating an object with the feedback values as properties dynamically.

For example, you can run the same mapReduce operation simply as:

```
map = function() {
    if (!this.feedback) return;
    var obj = {};
    obj[this.feedback] = 1;    
    emit(this.model, obj);
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
   var counts = {};
   values.forEach(function(v) {
        for(var k in v) { 
            if(!counts[k]) 
                counts[k] = 0
            counts[k] += v[k];
        }
    });

    return counts;
};

myMapReduce = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "colectionNAme",
    "map": map,
    "reduce" : reduce, 
    "out": "mappedResults"
});

db[myMapReduce.result].find();
```